# Curvature of plane curve, formula disagrees with Mathematica?

Tags: derivatives, curvature, wolfram-alpha

I have the following equation

$$y=\pi\ln(2x)$$

And when I ask Mathematica/WolframAlpha for the curvature I get

$$K=\frac{\pi x}{(x^2+\pi^2)^{3/2}}$$

However the formula for curvature of a plane curve is:

$$K = \frac{|y''|}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}$$

Which when using

$$y'=\frac{\pi}{x}$$
$$y''=-\frac{\pi}{x^2}$$

Which are both taken from WolframAlpha\Mathematica we find

$$K = \frac{\pi}{(1+ \frac{\pi^2}{x^2})^{3/2}x^2}$$

I've tested for equivalence between the two functions in Mathematica and they aren't the same. Can someone please explain how the Mathematica answer for curviture is reached or verify that my calculated curvature is correct?

Comment: By the chain rule, $$y' = \frac{\pi}{2x} \frac{d}{dx}(2x) = \frac{\pi}{2x}\cdot 2 = \frac{\pi}{x}.$$

Comment: @Gage no because $\frac{d}{dx}\ln{x}$ is $\frac{x'}{x}$ which in this case is $\frac{2\pi}{2x}=\frac{\pi}{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both the same. Note $$\left(1 + \frac{\pi^2}{x^2}\right)^{3/2} = \left(\frac{x^2 + \pi^2}{x^2}\right)^{3/2} = \frac{(x^2 + \pi^2)^{3/2}}{x^3}$$ So $$\frac{\pi}{\left(1 + \frac{\pi^2}{x^2}\right)^{3/2}x^2} = \frac{\pi}{\frac{(x^2 + \pi^2)^{3/2}}{x}} = \frac{\pi x}{(x^2 + \pi^2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Ok so now my question is how come WolframAlpha doesn't know the two are equivalent?

Comment: Maybe because they are not equal at $x = 0$ (your expression of $K$ is not defined at $x = 0$). But $y = \pi \ln(2x)$ is defined for $x > 0$, so since the two expressions of $K$ agree for $x > 0$, there's no need to worry.